# Ford Tractor 5600

Tags: ford, fuel-system, diesel, fuel-injectors, tractor

This is a older tractor. My question relates to the fuel system. The older fuel injectors don't have any external seals? All of them seat and 3 don't leak but one does.

I was looking for a seal but it didn't have any not even on the tip. So I'm wondering if they have a torque spec or how does it use a pressurized fuel system with no o-rings or gasket?

For those interested in specific application type: motor casting number # D5NN6015H

This places it in 75'

MODEL #LA254(6)(G)(C)(last digit maybe)
Production #8H22B
Serial # *c580840*

[image]

Comment: What year is that bad boy?

Comment: Not sure but think 65 70s

Comment: Maybe you could find a serial number to identify it.  Is this a diesel?

Comment: Yes diesel.. I will divide a serial number tomorrow night PST....

Comment: https://www.google.com/imgres?imgurl=http://d323w7klwy72q3.cloudfront.net/i/a/2014/20140226ag/F8165.JPG&imgrefurl=http://www.purplewave.com/cgi-bin/mnlist.cgi?140226/F8165&h=690&w=758&tbnid=ELf2_SwaiEJDEM:&docid=iO39_fwDmvES4M&hl=en&ei=STCdVvXbJsmwjwOz17eoCA&tbm=isch&client=safari&ved=0ahUKEwi1pL6QgLTKAhVJ2GMKHbPrDYUQMwgfKAMwAw

Comment: Above is the same tractor....

Comment: No prob.  Hopefully your question gets swarmed.

Comment: I think a picture is needed here. Does the injector look like [this](http://m.ebay.com/itm/Ford-Tractor-Fuel-Injector-Injection-Nozzle-2300-3000-5000-2110LC-3400-3500-3550-/251979779128?nav=SEARCH)?

Comment: http://www.ebay.com/bhp/ford-tractor-injector        This is a link to the injector type.... Still can't figure out this picture bit...

Comment: While not the same, I had to put an 8-71 Detroit Diesel once. I don't remember the injectors having seals in them, but they did require a specific torque (I over torqued them the first time, so remember this vividly). What I'm suggesting is this might be the same way.

Comment: Where is it leaking at? Where the injector lines go in to the injector? Or at the base?

Comment: While the answer below is true for some machines, this does seam odd. Heavy equipment back to the '50s has had small brass watchers. I would check with your Ford dealer to get information on this model.

Answer (score 1):

What you are seeing is the use of fit type to form a positive seal. Older vehicles used harder materials (not to be mistaken for toughness or strength) for most parts. As a result it was possible to use an interference fit or a transition fit to form a seal. Attached is an image explaining this.  Essentially, the fit is literally to tight for any fluid to flow through.

[image]